# Is $X_n = o_p(\sqrt{n})$ equivalent to $X_n = O_p(1)$?

Tags: probability

Suppose $X_n = o_p(\sqrt{n})$, I want to show it is equivalent to $X_n = O_p(1)$.

Since $X_n = o_p(\sqrt{n})$, we have $X_n = \sqrt{n} o_p(1)$. Since $\sqrt{n}=O_p(1)$, we have $X_n = O_p(1)O_p(1) = O_p(1)$.

Conversely, suppose $X_n = O_p(1)$, then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}X_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}O_p(1) = o(1)O_p(1)$, which implies $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}X_n =o_p(1)$, i.e. $X_n =o_p(\sqrt{n})$.

I used the fact that $\sqrt{n}=O_p(1)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=o(1)$ in above argument. However, while knowing $\sqrt{n}=O(1)$ is incorrect for sure, I highly doubt $\sqrt{n}=O_p(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Careful! The equivalence you are trying to prove is actually not true!**

First, let's tackle the proof you provided: unfortunately we have that $\sqrt{n}≠O_p(1)$, so the proof for $X_n = O_p(1)$ if $X_n = o_p(\sqrt{n})$ is not correct.

To verify that this is the case we can just show that $\sqrt{n}$ does not satisfy the definition for being in $O_p(1)$. This is evident because for any $M$ when we take $n$ big enough we have that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1}>M\right) = 1,$$
as $\sqrt{n}$ diverges to $\infty$, which implies what we wanted to prove.

However, it turns out that the statement is false. Consider the sequence of random variables $X_n = n^{1/4}$. Then we have both that $X_n = o_p(\sqrt{n})$ and that $X_n ≠ O_p(1)$. Once again, to prove these facts we can just verify that the sequence satisfies the definitions.

The proof that $X_n ≠ O_p(1)$ is very similar to the proof that $\sqrt{n} ≠ O_p(1)$: just replace the square root by the fourth root.

Then we just need to prove that $X_n = o_p(\sqrt{n})$. But that happens because
$$\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{4}}$$
so in particular the sequence converges almost surely (and then in probability) to 0.

As a remark, some intuition that may prove useful in making sense of this: note that $o_p(\sqrt{n})$ could be thought of as "a little bit smaller than $\sqrt{n}$...", but since that sequence diverges there are many other sequences in between constant sequences and this one that also fall in this category, some of which diverge. I got my example thinking about this, but other sequences can also be proposed: $n^\alpha$ with $\alpha < \frac{1}{2}$, $\log(n)$, and many others.

Finally, the proof for the other implication is indeed correct, and it does hold that $O_p(1) \subseteq o_p(\sqrt{n})$.